# Change geany theme entirely

Tags: colors, geany

I know how to change the editor color (view->Change color them...)

But I want to change the **entire geany window** (screenshot) to dark. is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Short answer : yes !!

I found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185115 :

> With gtk+ ≥ 3.12 you can load a specific theme and its variant (dark,
>   light) on a per-application1 basis via the environment variable
>   GTK_THEME=theme:variant. As per the gtk+ reference manual:
>
> GTK_THEME.  If set, makes GTK+ use the named theme instead of the
>   theme that is specified by the gtk-theme-name setting [...] It is also
>   possible to specify a theme variant to load, by appending the variant
>   name with a colon, like this: GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark.
>
> So, to load the dark variant you would run:
>
> GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark gedit
>
> Likewise, to achieve the opposite (when the default theme is dark),
>   you load the light variant:
>
> GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light gedit
>
> Note that if you want to use it via a custom launcher (.desktop file)
>   you'll have to prepend env to the command in the Exec line:
>
> Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark eog %U
>
> 1: Worth noting that - as per the devs decision - newer gnome-terminal
>   has its own configuration via menu > preferences and it ignores the
>   theme. Also, since this is rather new stuff, some gtk+ 3 applications
>   might not (yet) honor the GTK_THEME env variable (nautilus is one of
>   them).

---

Also you will need to use a custom icon set for this application, so I found on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440374 :

> For particular icon set per-application basis :
>
> Derived from Except some applications (like VLC) from using the
>   current gtk3 theme
>
> ```
> create any folder path/to/FOLDER
> create a icons/ folder inside it
> put your desired icon set folder in it and rename that folder with the name of current icon set
> ```
>
> After that you can force the use of this icon set with :
>
> XDG_DATA_DIRS=/path/to/FOLDER/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS
>
> For dark theme you can use breeze-dark icon set
>
> Cinnamon use metacity border-decoration, this is in themes/metacity-1/
>   folder. I don't know how to customize it for a specific application.
>   The XDG_DATA_DIRS hack above won't work.
>
> So if you want custom theme and icons, you can write in a terminal :
>
> GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark XDG_DATA_DIRS=/path/to/FOLDER/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS
>
> And for launching app with these settings in application .desktop file
>   :
>
> Exec=sh -c "GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark
>   XDG_DATA_DIRS=/path/to/FOLDER/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS  %F"

Comment: Can this be done on windows?

Comment: `Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark geany %F` in `/usr/share/applications/geany.desktop` works for Ubuntu 18.04, gtk 3.22.30-1ubu. I have also added `alias geany='GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark geany'` in `.bash_aliases` for launches from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "change the entire geany window to dark" but aren't too particular, you can simply locate the geany.css file (on my system it is located at `/usr/share/geany/geany.css`) and copy it to `/home/yourusername/.config/geany/geany.css`.

Then modify the new file by adding the following rules to the top of the css file.  Geany will look in the config folder for this new file and use it preferentially.  I believe it will also be preserved during upgrades etc.

```
/* Add these rules to the top of geany.css file to make dark */

* {
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    border-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

button,
button *,
*:hover,
*:hover>* {
    background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}
```

For me this is enough.

[screen shot for simple dark geany style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd4LI.png)

Comment: Logged in to upvote. Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark eog %U but your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is an old question, but it is what I found whan I face the same problem, and the answer below doesn't help me very much. However, I find a workaround that works on windows OS from the [issue #1344](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1344#issuecomment-597588645) posted in the geany project. Therefore, I post the answer here in case that some other people will find a plausible solution when they come here for an answer.

Comment: If you have done something similar for your *Ubuntu* installation, could you update your answer to include the steps for people using Geany on Ubuntu? Windows directory paths are generally different from Linux paths.

Comment: @Matigo Sure, I will.